# Wordpress permalinks problem

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I changed my wordpress permalinks to %pagname%. Prior to doing this i posted two blog entries (the site is brand new). My static pages navigate fine after the changes but when you click on my posts you get 404'd. Has anyone else had this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

isn't the permalink structure supposed to be

```
/%postname%/
```

with that the posts will have a nice url, and not using pagename, or pagname as you have it?
Open your .htaccess file and check if anything is written, if so highlight it all and delete it, wordpress will fall back to the original default state,

then within the admin->settings->permalink section select custom and paste in that, and click save, if wordpress reloads the page and the htaccess info is pinned to the bottom of the page then copy and paste that to your .htaccess file, if its not then its been written to your file already...

Answer (score 1):

You probably fixed it by now, but try adding "/%postname%/" after "/%pagename%/. I was having the same problem but changed mine to read /%pagename%/%postname%/ and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 1):

check .htaccess file permission has 777 
I did like that and works.

Answer (score 0):

Reset your permalinks and make sure .htaccess is writable: [Using Permalinks « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

Comment: Did both of these things with no luck. I published a new post and that still doesnt link correctly.

Comment: Both of what things? Reset permalinks in Settings and made sure the changes were written to .htaccess?

Comment: I'm not sure where in the settings there is a reset permalinks option but my .htaccess id writable.

Comment: We desperately need clarity here. So you make that permalinks setting change directly in .htaccess? Or in WordPress Dashboard/Settings/Permalinks and then edited .htaccess, if/when Wordpress said it couldn't update .htaccess? If you made the change directly in .htaccess, then Wordpress doesn't know what you did, as it stores permalink settings in the database. If you made the change in Settings/Permalinks, then did Wordpress say the changes were saved to .htaccess?

Comment: Not sure how I could be more clear but here goes. 1. Wrote 2 blog posts. 2.Changed permalinks via dashboard to %pagename% 3.When blog entry links are clicked i get 404'd.

Comment: Few things funnier than a revenge downvote for an answer that was correct in the first place :)

Comment: It appears that to "reset" permalinks you just need to choose a different setting (e.g. Default), save changes and then change it back to what it was. I was getting a 404 on my feed URL since upgrading Wordpress but after switching settings like that it now works.

Answer (score 0):

Check your apache configuration and verify that for the directory in which you store your Wordpress installation you have following settings enabled (probably there will be more, but you need at least these):

```
<Directory var/www/>
FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```